# Suggestions on a good way to promote a free resource

Tags: php

As a developer, I've learned a heck of a lot from the global community and I believe like any community, you need to participate and contribute.

I've worked on several small projects that I want to offer up for free, but I want them to actually be used.

For the sincerity of this post, I am not going to promote them here.

What are some good ways to offer a free resource like a widget that does x,y, and z, for free.  With an honest-to-god intent to just contribute?

Comment: I'm voting to close your question because I don't believe advertising tactics fall under programming Q&A.

Comment: i don't know if it's totally off-topic - these are the sorts of questions a lot of us might have - he has made it community wiki so he's not rep-whoring here

Comment: Mark, I understand.  I didn't include any URL's or links.  I did make it a community wiki.  This is a sincere request.  Programmers are not idiots...they know when it's a scam to make money vs. when it's a resource.  I've got a few programs that I'd like to share but I don't want to spend a ton of time blogging or posting in places where it will go wasted.

Comment: @jerebear, I understand your rationale for asking this here and respect that you're not using this as an avenue for advertisement, it'll take 4 others to agree with me, but my opinion is that this still isn't the right forum.  I'm not in the habit of voting to close without leaving a reason, my note isn't supposed to discourage those who feel that this is on topic from responding, merely to explain the action.

Comment: @stephemurdoch: A lot of us might also have questions about how to cook a good meal, but that doesn't make it on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Assuming it's open source, add to freshmeat for example to help people find it.
2. Write **really** good documentation, with examples etc.  There's load of code out there which is lacking documentation making it pretty useless no matter how good the code is.
3. Make it easy for people to report bugs, suggest features, etc.

Comment: I had never heard about Freshmeat before.  That's awesome!

Comment: Word of mouth is best, obviously that takes time.  Need to help people who google for 'php widget xyz free' find your project.

Answer (score 1):

make a screencast showing how you made the software - other programmers will watch the video and may in-turn blog about it

i'm sure you'll get better suggestions than that though, good luck